# Retrieve Stripe charge status from used source token - Node + MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, stripe-payments, credit-card

Let's say my user submits a credit card token to my server to complete a purchase. Then I save this token in my user's cart, and in the sequence, I charge it.

I receive a success response with the charge id and, suddenly, my server stops working just before I can store this charge id in my user's cart.

The charge was definitely made, but I couldn't save it in my database to generate the user's order and make the products available, so I don't know if it succeeded or not.

What I want to do is to mitigate any possibility of duplicate payments. I've looked into the entire Stripe's API but I just couldn't find any information about if it's possible to retrieve a charge using the card token that was used to create it.

Every time when my server reboots, some processes are triggered to verify database integrity (I'm using MongoDB, by the way), and one of those processes tries to make charges for all user carts (with already generated card tokens) that were left in a "waiting payment" state. If a card token wasn't charged yet, everything works well, but if it was charged already, I just don't know if the charge succeeded or not, so I can't update my cart to a consistent state.

I can retrieve the card token by using "stripe.tokens.retrieve(token).then(...", but I just know if it was used or not. I have to find a way to discover if it was charged and if it succeeded.

I've tried to store the card token as a metadata of my charge, so I'd be able to retrieve charges that contain this card token as metadata, but it seems that this kind of query is not possible.

Does anyone know how to overcome this issue or any better logic to grant payment consistency in a MongoDB payment implementation?

Comment: You can generate and save a unique ID at the beginning of the cart checkout attempt, and use this as an idempotency key when making the charge request : https://stripe.com/docs/api#idempotent_requests Then if you have a crash, you can safely retry the request, and if you use the same key, it won't create a duplicate charge(you just get the original response back)

Comment: @karllekko, thank you very much, this will definetely help me! I've just tested this feature, but I still have one problem. Before I charge the card token generated client-side, I store it in the user's cart, so if I have a crash, I can charge it again without the need of the user to remake the payment, but the same token can't be used twice, even if an idempotency  key is passed. Do you have any suggestion in this case? I'd like to avoid making my users remake failed payments manually. Thanks again!

Comment: @karllekko, I'm sorry, my mistake! If a card token generated client-side is charged more than once, if an idempotency key was passed I do receive a successful response, without creating duplicate charges. It was my code that was catching an error coming from another async function that was executed before the charge attempt in my server. So, this is the answer I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As @karllekko commented, this is the answer to my question:

"You can generate and save a unique ID at the beginning of the cart checkout attempt, and use this as an idempotency key when making the charge request : stripe.com/docs/api#idempotent_requests Then if you have a crash, you can safely retry the request, and if you use the same key, it won't create a duplicate charge(you just get the original response back)"

And following my logic, I'm making those failed payments attempts to be executed again without the need of the user to retry it manually, so I'm storing the card-token generated client-side in my user's cart and in the sequence I'm charging this same token and using it as the idempotency key to avoid duplicate payments, as they are unique within Stripe's DB.

This is the request that avoids duplicate payments and always gives me the same response, successful or not, for the same card-token, and makes it possible to grant a consistent state to my user's cart:

```
stripe.charges.create(
        {
          amount: amount,
          currency: 'usd',
          source: token
        },
        {
          idempotency_key: token
        }
      ).then(
        res => resolve(res),// Proceed to a success card/order state and allow products/services to be accessed by user. If an attempt of make duplicate payments using the same card-token happens, you'll receive the same success response and will be able to proceed to the same success card/order state.
        err => reject({e: err, m: 'PAYMENT_ERROR', i: 'STRIPE_CHARGE_ERROR'})// An error occurred with the original charge request, so you'll have to rollback to the pre-checkout cart state. Even if you couldn't get the original error response, using an idempotency key will give you the exactly same error response in this step when you retry the charge attempt for this same card-token, so you know you have to rollback.
      )
```

Thanks, @karllekko!